# How do I retrieve a specific order in Shopify Liquid?

Tags: shopify, liquid

### The problem

I'm creating a proxy app page for a store in Shopify and would like to get a specific order based on the order id using liquid code.

The proxy page will have an url like this: /tools/integrator/order/{id} where {id} is the order id. The proxy page will create liquid code and a mix of other information from a custom database.

I would like to get the specific order with something like:

```
<p>
  Created: customer.orders[xyz].created_at
</p>
```

where the xyz number is the order id, not the array index. The orders array doesn't seem to have an option to get an order by the order id but only by the index.

### My current Non optimised solution

The only way I've found is to create a for loop and compare the id of each order with the id that I need to get:

```
{% for order in customer.orders %}
  {% if order.id == 4225044174 %}
    <p>Order found!</p>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I get the order by order id without a loop?

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: @kjones I didn't find a better solution for this.

Comment: unfortunate, will keep looking or just settle on what you are doing above. ty though